# Threading and Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, multithreading, begininvoke

I have the following:

```
   ThreadStart startThread =
     delegate
     {
             mySocket.StartListen();
     };
```

mySocket is now looping on a Listen() when I:

```
new Thread(startThread).Start();
```

Here is StartListen:

```
public void StartListen()
{
 Object locker = new Object();

 // Lock resources
 lock (locker)
 {
  S = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
       System.Net.Sockets.SocketType.Stream,
       System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp);
  S.Blocking = false;

  try
  {
   S.Bind(serverEP);
   S.Listen(1000);
   isListening = true;

   /*
    * While statement not required here because AcceptConnection()
    * method instructs the socket to BeginAccept() again...
    */
   //while (true)
   //{
   connectDone.Reset();
   S.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptConnection), Channel);
   connectDone.WaitOne();
   //}
  }
  catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException SockEx)
  {
   Console.WriteLine("*****[" + name + "] " + SockEx.SocketErrorCode + ":");
   Console.WriteLine("*****[" + name + "] " + SockEx.Message);
  }
 }
}
```

Because of the asynchronous methods things don't really 'finish' and return a signal for anything else to continue. Any commands I implement after the Thread.Start() above are not working properly. For instance, in StartListen, note that I have an `isListening = true`. After I start the thread, I want to use the property IsListening. It is always returned as false.

How should I be starting the Thread. Would an asynchronous method (i.e. ThreadStart.BeginInvoke()) be preferrable? Isn't that similar to using a ManualResetEvent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark `isListening` as [`volatile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx).  As I understand it, you're referencing this flag in two different threads.  Normally, data shared between threads must be synchronized, but it doesn't appear you're doing that.  However, given that the flag is a bool type, you don't technically have to synchronize access to it because the .NET framework guarantees that reads and writes from bool types are atomic (I *think* I'm saying that correctly...someone please correct me if that it not technically correct).  But, in order to make sure that reads from that type actually get the most recent value, you need to mark it as `volatile`.

Also, you'd be better off using the `TcpListener` class instead of trying to do this with the `Socket` class.  What you're doing is not wrong, but the `TcpListener` class would make your code simpler to read and maintain, IMO.

Finally, the `locker` object you're using doesn't really do anything since it is local to the `StartListen()` method.  In order for synchronization objects to have any effect, they need to be accessible to the threads that need serialized access to shared data.  The way you're doing it here, other threads cannot access the `locker` variable, thus rendering it useless.

Comment: I haven't used 'volatile' before. I'll read up on it. Using TcpListener is not completely out of the question. However, I already have all the asynchronous operations written and working with the Sockets class. I opted for working with the base class rather than taking the easy way out on TcpListener/TcpClient. :)

Comment: Using the `Socket` class is not wrong.  It's just that `TcpListener` is much easier since it was designed expressly for how you're using `Socket`.